# Erro ao instalar pacote "summarytools" no R

Tags: r

Tentei baixar o **pacote summarytools** e informa esse erro:

> library("summarytools")
> **Error**: package or namespace load failed for ‘summarytools’:
> .onLoad falhou em loadNamespace() para 'magick', detalhes:
> chamada: set_magick_tempdir(tempdir())
> erro: function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp

Como resolver?

Comment: Experimente atualizar o pacote *magick* (ou faça uma atualização completa dos pacotes instalados. Persistindo o problema, edite a questão para incluir detalhes como versão do R e das dependências do pacote, sistema, etc.

Comment: Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68416435/rcpp-package-doesnt-include-rcpp-precious-remove). E também [este outro post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68569969/8245406), muito recente do SO em Inglês.

Answer (score 0):

As aspas vão apenas no *install.packages*. Experimente rodar o comando *library* sem as aspas.

```
install.packages("summarytools")
library(summarytools)
```